# HTML header trouble. Why is there spacing?

Tags: html, css, header, css-float, format

Before i created a search bar or the menu-bar-search items the header looked great! Great spacing between the logo and links, they were centered on screen...etc. Now there is a GIANT gap to the left and right of the search bar and everything is leaning on the right side of the page. I've played with the menu-bar-overlay size and the size of all three elements within it, I've tried every suggestion I've found googgling for the last three days. Nothing works :/ stack overflow, you are my final hope. Please help.

#### My style.css

```
#main-container {

    width: 100%;
    min-height: 800px;
}

#menu-bar {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('../images/menu.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#menu-bar-overlay {
    width: 1450px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#menu-bar-left {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 8px;
    background-image: url('../images/blog_small.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#menu-bar-right {
    float: left;
    width: 670px;
    height: 50px;

}

#menu-bar-right li {
    color: white;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    font-weight: normal;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    border-right-style: groove;
    border-right-color: rgba(47,173,255,0.5); 
    padding-right: 8px;
}

#menu-bar-right li a:link, 
#menu-bar-right li a:active, 
#menu-bar-right li a:visited {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-bar-right li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(211,211,211,1);
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-bar-search {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

#### My header.jsp

```
<div id="main-container">

    <div id="menu-bar">

        <div id="menu-bar-overlay">

            <div id="menu-bar-left"></div>

            <div id="menu-bar-right">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="./index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./admin">Admin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./addArticle">Add Article</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./admin">Update Article</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./admin">Delete Article</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                <div id ="menu-bar-search">
                <form method = "post" action = "searchResults" name = "search">
                    <input type = "text" maxlength = "20" id = "search-field" required>
                    <input type = "submit" id = "search-button" value = "Search" style = "float:left; width:100px; margin-left:5px;">
                </form>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="top-picture">
        <div id="picture-overlay-spacer"></div>
        <div id="picture-overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="header-spacer"></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of it pls

Comment: Don't know if this will take you there but http://jsfiddle.net/dThv6/1/ is the address i've got looking at it over in jsfiddle. Doesn't look quite so pretty though pointing to empty jpg's. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#menu-bar-right` has a width of 670px, which is much wider than its contents.  Try setting that to `auto`, and then it'll stop pushing your search bar over to the left.

Your `#menu-bar-search` also has a width of 300px, which is why it might be appearing to have extra space to right of it.

Last, `#menu-bar-overlay` has a width of 1450px, which might be wider than you want it in many scenarios. Since it's so wide, the other content won't be able to fill it up.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dThv6/

Comment: I'm at work right now, but that's a good suggestion. I'll try it out as soon as i get home. Hope it works!

Comment: Thanks! This didn't quite finish the fix but it got me close enough to tinker the last bit myself with a little experimentation! I definately had some <div> fields inflated past the size requirments of their contents :P

Answer (score 0):

Tried changing the size of bar-search?

```
width: 300px; to width: 530px; or a little less
```

Comment: Yeah, i've already tired changing all the sizes of the various styles in the css and also directly in the object creation over in the jsp to no avail :P Thanks though.